# hyperledger composer & access security

Tags: acl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am currently building a network with a lot of different company with each one running a node.

The model is basically one big asset. A company might access couple of property and be restricted from other.

I saw that asset property permission is not possible.

**The only solution I can see would be to create sub asset of that main asset and apply different permission and deny the possibility to host a node ?**

Thanks a lot for your ideas & suggestions.

Jonathan.

Answer (score 0):

**Hyperledger Composer:**

I suggest you to split your asset in smaller ones and implement the right access control for each one.

However you can implement specific logics in the transaction processor based on the identity / participant which is invoking the chaincode.

For example:

```
// Get the current participant.
var currentParticipant = getCurrentParticipant();

if (currentParticipant.getFullyQualifiedType() == 'org.example.ParticipantOfCompanyA') {
  //do something
} else if (currentParticipant.getFullyQualifiedType() == 'org.example.ParticipantOfCompanyB') {
  //do something else
}
```

Here the link to the official documentation:

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/api/runtime-api#getcurrentparticipant

**Hyperledger Fabric:**

From Fabric v1.2 is possible to create private data between organizations on the same channel.

Here the link to the official documentation:

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private-data/private-data.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes your solution work perfectly in case of a participant that does not host a node. However if the participant host a node It is now possible with a new feature implemented in Fabric 1.2: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/private-data/private-data.html